# JSON file not being read properly

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to read a JSON file in C#, which I'm pretty new in. Here's the layout of the Json in question:

```
{
  "stickerBundles": [
    {
      "id": "ludoBundle",
      "stickers": [
        {
          "id": "compter",
          "title": "Compter",
          "code": "LUDO WS1001",
          "loadingScreenColor": "#",
          "assetBundles": [
            {
              "name": "animations",
              "assets": [ "Assets/AnimationCompter/Prefabs/Scene_Compter.prefab" ],
              "buildPath": [ "ar_animations-android-etc2", "ar_animations-ios-new" ]

            },
            {
              "name": "androidStory",
              "assets": [
                "Assets/Textures/Sprites/Histoires/Compter/Default/story-compter-alpha.spriteatlas",
                "Assets/Textures/Sprites/Histoires/Compter/Default/story-compter-noalpha.spriteatlas"
              ],
              "buildPath": [ "histoires/compter-android-etc2" ]
            },
            {
              "name": "iosNewStory",
              "assets": [
                "Assets/Textures/Sprites/Histoires/Compter/Default/story-compter-alpha.spriteatlas",
                "Assets/Textures/Sprites/Histoires/Compter/Default/story-compter-noalpha.spriteatlas"
              ],
              "buildPath": [ "histoires/compter-ios-new" ]
            },
            {
              "name": "iosOldStory",
              "assets": [
                "Assets/Textures/Sprites/Histoires/Compter/iOS/old/story-compter-alpha.spriteatlas",
                "Assets/Textures/Sprites/Histoires/Compter/iOS/old/story-compter-noalpha.spriteatlas"
              ],
              "buildPath": [ "histoires/compter-ios-old" ]
            }
          ],
          "downloads": [
            "ar_animations",
            "histoires/compter",
            "games/seekandfind"
          ]
        }, (...)
```

I'm trying to read it like this:

```c#
public static StickerBundlesList GetStickersConfig()
    {
        string jsonString = File.ReadAllText(STICKER_CONFIG_FILENAME);
        return JsonUtility.FromJson<StickerBundlesList>(jsonString);
    }
```

The object I get as a result is this:

```json
{
    "stickerBundles": [
        {
            "id": "ludoBundle"
        }, (...)
```

meaning that I cannot work with anything other than stickerBundles.id.

I made a class for StickerBundlesList (which only contains an array of StickerBundle) and structs for StickerBundle, Sticker and Bundle. StickerBundlesList and StickerBundle are serializable. Here's what they look like:

StickerBundlesList.cs:

```c#
public partial class StickerResources
{
    [System.Serializable]
    public class StickerBundlesList
    {
        public StickerBundle[] stickerBundles;
    }
}
```

StickerBundle.cs:

```c#
public partial class StickerResources
{
    [System.Serializable]
    public struct StickerBundle
    {
        public string id;
        public Sticker[] stickers;
    }
}
```

StickerResources.cs:

```c#
public partial class StickerResources : SceneSingleton<StickerResources>
{
    public TextAsset textJson;
    public const string STICKER_CONFIG_FILENAME = "Assets/Resources/StickerResources/StickerResources.json";
    public struct Sticker
    {
        public string id;
        public string title;
        public string code;
        public string loadingScreenColor;
        public Bundle[] assetBundles;
    }
    public struct Bundle
    {
        public string name;
        public string[] assets;
        public string[] buildPath;
    }

    public StickerBundlesList stickerBundleList = new StickerBundlesList();

    private void Awake()
    {
        stickerBundleList = JsonUtility.FromJson<StickerBundlesList>(textJson.text);
    }

    public static StickerBundlesList GetStickersConfig()
    {
        string jsonString = File.ReadAllText(STICKER_CONFIG_FILENAME);
        return JsonUtility.FromJson<StickerBundlesList>(jsonString);
    }
}
```

I would love to access all my JSON as a C# object. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: +1 to the question for the necessary/almost needed inputs to answer the question :-) After looking at the provided details it appears just the non-existence of {System.Serializable] for `Sticker` and `Bundle` `struct`s. I think after adding this serialization should work. Not related to the question, though I'll always try to avoid Singletons in a project, they lead to more coupling than anything else in the project.

Answer (score 0):

I think part of the problem might be your class/struct nesting? Maybe un-nest those for now until you get the serialization working, and then if you want to reorganize things later try that again.

I don't think you included all the source code, so I had to extrapolate a little.  For example, I was able to get this working in LINQPad:

```
void Main()
{
    var jsonString = @"
{
  ""stickerBundles"": [

    {
        ""id"": ""ludoBundle"",
      ""stickers"": [

        {
            ""id"": ""compter"",
          ""title"": ""Compter"",
          ""code"": ""LUDO WS1001"",
          ""loadingScreenColor"": ""#"",
          ""assetBundles"": [

            {
                ""name"": ""animations"",
              ""assets"": [ ""Assets/AnimationCompter/Prefabs/Scene_Compter.prefab"" ],
              ""buildPath"": [ ""ar_animations-android-etc2"", ""ar_animations-ios-new"" ]

            }]
        }]
    }]
}
";
    //string jsonString = File.ReadAllText(STICKER_CONFIG_FILENAME);
    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<StickerBundlesList>(jsonString);
    
    result.Dump();
}

[System.Serializable]
public class StickerBundlesList
{
    public StickerBundle[] stickerBundles;
}

[System.Serializable]
public struct StickerBundle
{
    public string id;
    public Sticker[] stickers;
}

[System.Serializable]
public struct Sticker
{
    public string id;
    public string title;
    // etc
}
```

Which outputs the object hierarchy (StickerBundleList > StickerBundle > Sticker):

[image: picture of data dumped from serialized object]

I used LINQPad to test this, but you should be able to throw this into a new C# console app or something to test it. Also, I used the JSON.Net JSON library. I'm guessing the difference in our libraries is *not* what makes this work, but if you think it could be, check the settings for your library. I'm using the default settings for JSON.Net.